# Will specifying a model in partial view affect the whole razor body or only the partial view area?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

this is my partial View

```
@model MyModel<br>
@using (Html.BeginForm("NewOrder", "Order", FormMethod.Post))
{
    <div class="form-inline">
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerMessage, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerMessage, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CustomerName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-1" })
            <div class="col-md-2">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.CustomerName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Now if I use this in a view will, this effect my whole page or only the section I have rendered this partial view will be affected??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Now if I use this in a view will, this effect my whole page or only
>   the section I have rendered this partial view will be affected??

No, it will not affect the whole page. It will affect only the section that you have rendered this partial view. Actually this is one of Partial Views benefits. You can render small pieces of html here and there without affecting the whole page in which they are included.

> how to pass a Model to a partial view?

You can do so like this:

```
 @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Partial.cshtml", Model.PartialViewModel)
```

I suggest, in the `Model` of your View you define a property that would be associated with the model you want to pass to your partial view. This make sense, since in order to render the View, you have to render also the Partial Views that are contained to it. So it is a good practice to have all the model that are needed by the Partial Views as properties of the Views Model.

Comment: Thank you. And can you suggest me how to pass a Model to a partial view? I tried
`@Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_Partial.cshtml", Myproject.Core.Order.OrderModel())`
The Model is in another class library. But I am getting an error.